# How to find which screen (and thus port) the VNC UI for a kvm guest has? Or how to assign it 

Tags: linux, vnc, kvm-virtualization

Is there a straightforward way to find the VNC screen (i.e. port number minus 5900) onto which a KVM guest is bound?

My guests are all configured to run with VNC enabled, but the order in which they occupy the ports is random.

Alternately, is there a way to assign them in the configuration (of guest or host), so that each respective guest will occupy a predefined port?!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you're using `libvirt`, you can just ask it!

```
root@onhost1:~# virsh list
 Id Name                 State
----------------------------------
  1 one-34               running
  2 one-36               running
  3 one-38               running

root@onhost1:~# virsh vncdisplay one-34
:34

root@onhost1:~# virsh vncdisplay 1
:34
```

*(my particular correlation of name to VNC display port is due to the use of Open Nebula)*

EDIT: Nowadays, you can use domdisplay to get the URI of the display whether it's VNC or Spice:

```
○ → virsh domdisplay win-michael
vnc://127.0.0.1:0

○ → for dom in $(virsh list --name); do echo -n "$dom: "; virsh domdisplay $dom; done
win-michael-m: vnc://127.0.0.1:0
```

---

Here's a one-liner to execute this for all running guests at once:

```
for i in $(virsh -q list|awk '{print $2}'|sort); do
  echo -e "\033[01;31m$i\033[00m -> $(virsh vncdisplay $i)"
done
```

Also made it into a function that sorts output by port number:

```
function vnc-list
{
  for i in $(virsh -q list|awk '{print $2}'|sort); do
    PORTNUM=$(virsh vncdisplay $i|cut -f 2 -d ':')
    printf "% 2d: \033[01;32m%.20s\033[00m\n" "$PORTNUM" "$i";
  done | sort -n
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch for that. It's spot-on what I was looking for. I'm going to edit a Bash one-liner into your answer for completeness.

Comment: Hmm, well the on-liner I edited in apparently got edited into a three-liner. Makes me look stupid as if I didn't know what the difference between 1 and 3 is, but I promise that the version I had was cramming this onto one single line ;) ... don't have edit-rights yet, so I'm at the mercy of others with this.

Comment: I edited it into a three-liner for readability and so it doesn't require scrolling to view.

Comment: Due to some reason in my install virsh vncdisplay does not show up the VNC port. "#virsh vncdisplay vm01  returns nothing". I have tigetvnc installed. And running Centos 6

Comment: @chandank you probably have a spice display - use the `domdisplay` command to get the more general URI

Answer (score 3):

I would run :

```
ps aux | grep "VM name/config"
```

Note the process ID and then

```
netstat -apn | grep "process ID"
```

This should show you are port open by that process.

Answer (score 2):

To set the display, simply explicitly provide the `-vnc <ip:display>` option to qemu-kvm.
See the [man page to qemu-kvm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/qemu-kvm), especially the `-vnc` parameter section for details.